# InitializeComponent(); in Prism Library Does not exist?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

using xamarin forms pcl & Prism Library

```
 public class App : PrismApplication
   {  
    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) 
    { }
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

        //InitializeComponent();
        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage");
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>("MainPage");
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<LoginPage>("LoginPage");
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ServicePage>("ServicePage");
    }

}
```

in MainActivity.cs

```
  public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        //TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        //ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));
    }
    public class AndroidInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
    {
        public void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
        }


    }
```

the main Page.cs

```
 namespace PRProject.Views
    {
        public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
   {
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackgroundImage = "Background.png";
    }
}
```

and MainPage.Xaml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PRProject.Views.MainPage" BackgroundImage="Background.png"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True">

  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="20,0,20,10">
    <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center">
      <StackLayout>


        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20">
          <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="signin.png">
              <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}" />
              </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
          </Grid>

        </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage>
```

and the view Model

```
namespace PRProject.ViewModels
    {
     public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
    {
    private INavigationService _navigationService;

    public DelegateCommand NavigateCommand { get; set; }
    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Navigate);
    }
    private void Navigate()
    {
        _navigationService.NavigateAsync("LoginPage");
    }
     }}
```

- the problem is

  1. i have no InitializeCompenent() to be called inside OnInitialized()
  2. when it Navigate to MainPage it appears as Blank Page
  3. Another Extra Issue in Main Activity if Main Activity class Inherit from 
     global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity it returns null exception
  4. inside Main Activity the Parameter of Registertype is IContainer but for me it is IUnityContainer.

Answer (score 2):

Your `App` class will only have a `InitializeComponent` method if it has an accompanying XAML file. If you don't, the easiest way to achieve this is by recreating the `App` class as a "Forms ContentPage XAML" from the New File dialog. Then make sure the XAML file also uses the `PrismApplication` class.

Your XAML file should look like this:

```xml
<prism:PrismApplication 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Unity;assembly=Prism.Unity.Forms"
    x:Class="SampleApp">
    <!-- other XAML can go here -->
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

Please note that there is no requirement to use a XAML file with Prism.Forms (although it is recommended in my opinion), so you can also just leave out the `InitializeComponent` call.

**Edit after receiving more information**

In your `MainPage.xaml`, you have placed a `ScrollView` in a `StackLayout`, where the `StackLayout` has `VerticalOptions` set to `End`. The `StackLayout` has no way of knowing how large it should become, since the `ScrollView` is its only child. Remove the outer `StackLayout` and most likely something will show up on the `MainPage`.

If you just want to try an easy way to rule out that Prism is the issue, you can also replace the XAML with a simple `Label` element.

Just another remark based on your XAML: try to avoid nesting unnecessary `StackLayouts`, as it will cause a performance hit.

Comment: i removed the scrollview and the mainpage was blank too but after a while it returned ( System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements) exception

Comment: Try with just a `Label` in your MainPage, to rule out any other issues. Is the MainPage constructor called?

Comment: yes the MainPage constructor is called successfully with no issues or exceptions but the page still Blank.

Comment: i tried also to create App.Xaml.cs but i have got this wired errorThe type or namespace name 'DryIoc' does not exist in the namespace 'Prism' (are you missing an assembly reference?).

Comment: I created a test application, adding your code and added 2 NuGet packages (both in the PCL and platform projects): Prism.Forms and Prism.Unity.Forms. If I just do that, I also get a blank page because of the `ScrollView` like I mentioned in my answer (set backgroundcolors for easy layout debugging). Adding just the `Label` makes it show up (if you set the Text property :-)). I suggest you start a new project from scratch and compare with that.

Comment: after adding Prism.DryIoc.forms besides Prism.Forms and Prism.Unity.Forms and i used the name space DryIoc instead of Unity in side MainActivity .i transfered  RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container) to  RegisterTypes(DryIoc.IContainer container) and in app.cs i used DryIoc instead of Unity as well and at the end it worked this was the solution.